# Zend - Configuration Data from Database

Tags: zend-framework

I am new to Zend and still learning.

I need to read some configuration data from the database and keep it in session. I want this data in all the pages, so I need to intercept all the request and check if the session contains the required data, if not I will fetch it from the database and put it in the session.

I would like to know the best place to put the code in. In Java we used to check that in a filter. I am guessing here I have to put this is in an Action Helper. Just wanted to check what options I have and what are the best practices.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that purposes you may use Zend_Registry singleton class for providing accessibility of session data from every point of ZF-project. For storing session data there are also several classes, e.g. Zend_Session class

Comment: Zend_Registry has nothing to do with a session, it only provides anything to the whole application, as a registry (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html) does. To have access to a Session you could use Zend_Session, yes, but not Zend_Registry.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely put this in a Controller Plugin class. eg.

```
Application_Controllerplugins_SessConfig extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
```

This way you can catch the request early on, and do whatever you want with the data... 
This is another answer of mine on SSL routing, but the logic is the same for the plugin class: [How to implement SSL in Zend MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777930/how-to-implement-ssl-in-zend-mvc/5638452#5638452)

Answer (score 0):

i am about to implement a similar solution whereby an application instance (which is to be rolled out to various customers) needs certain settings-data to be editable by admin via cms and thus am storing it in the db.  i am then going to retrieve and add these settings [as a sub-object] to the config class (which in turn is added to the registry in the bootstrap.  this seems like the cleanest solution to me as then all config data are stored in the one place, regardless of their source being an ini file or the db.

i'd be interested to hear other opinions on how this is done.

rob ganly